# consequence of a duplicate Session ID

Tags: security, session, sessionid

I know that the chance of duplication of Session ID is extremely rare. But still, I was pondering over the consequences of it.

I thought about a situation where the session ID is used to store the 'user ID' and 'logged in' state of a user.
So, if by chance a session ID got duplicated then a person might get access to someone else's dashboard if the 'logged in' state of session ID was true.

I don't have a clear idea if this situation could occur. Please clarify on the same.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not very likely or probable that you will generate two equal session ID's. Though of course this will depend on the algorithm that was used to generate the ID's.

A session ID would normally be generated based on a number of factors unique to the user, including IP and time generated; further pushing of the chances of a duplicate occurring.

But, to further safe-guard you could tie the session ID to the users location or IP to further prevent the slim chances.